# How can the Rosenbrock function be non-convex?

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am dealing with the Rosenbrock function

$$ f(x,y) = (1-x)^2 + 100(y-x^2)^2$$

I read online that this is a non convex function. However when I watch its graph, it looks like a convex function. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

[image: b]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example $$f\left(\frac{(-1,1)+(0,0)}2\right)=\frac{17}2>\frac52=\frac{f(-1,1)+f(0,0)}2$$ so $f$ is not convex. More systematically, one could note that the Hessian of $f$ is not always positive semi-definite.

Comment: This makes sense, but is something wrong with the figure? Isn't this the graph of a convex function?

Comment: @Thomas [This graphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function#/media/File:Rosenbrock_function.svg) is much better. In your graphic,  the highest order term, $x^4$, which is convex, completely dominates the view

Comment: Ah I see. Ok :) Thanks !

Comment: @Thomas You are welcome 